# Error while building wso2 kernel 4.0.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Can any one help for this error while building wso2 kernel 4.0.6:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project axis2-transport-rabbitmq-amqp: Could not resolve

dependencies for project org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-rabbitmq-amqp:bundle:

1.1.0-wso2v9: Could not find artifact com.rabbitmq.wso2:amqp-client:jar:3.0.3.wso2v1 in wso2-

maven2-repository (http://dist.wso2.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

What is the svn URL you used for checking out the code? In order to build carbon kernel 4.0.6 you should check out https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.0.0/patch-releases/4.0.6/ and build. If you haven't checkout from here, please use that location.

Comment: I think this user is trying to build the trunk.